# Resolve ambigious name in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

It is annoying typing full name of a class like 
`myNamespace.y.calendar cal = new myNamespace.y.calendar();` 
(because asp.net already has a class name called calendar in System.web.ui.webcontrolls).
So to resolve this we can use like

```
using Calendar = myNamespace.y.calendar;
Calendar cal = new Calendar();
```

But how to do the same thing in asp.net aspx page?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
<%@ Import Namespace="Calendar=myNamespace.y.calendar" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

A little more info about [Namespace Alias Qualifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c3ay4x3d%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).  Just importing the namespace may not be sufficient if your class name is ambiguous with another class from a different namespace:

```
using colAlias = System.Collections;
namespace System
{
    class TestClass
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            // Searching the alias:
            colAlias::Hashtable test = new colAlias::Hashtable();

            // Add items to the table.
            test.Add("A", "1");
            test.Add("B", "2");
            test.Add("C", "3");

            foreach (string name in test.Keys)
            {
                // Seaching the gloabal namespace:
                global::System.Console.WriteLine(name + " " + test[name]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```